# PyMuPDF insertTextBox inserting text but in mirrored form

Tags: python, pymupdf

```
import fitz
text_rectangle = fitz.Rect(450,20,550,120)
file_handle = fitz.open(input_file)
first_page = file_handle[0]
text = 'SAS Automation'
first_page.insertTextbox(text_rectangle, f'{text}')
file_handle.save(output_file)
```

Above code adds text in pdf in mirror form why I dont know I tried insertText method, morph attribute with inserTextbox but still no solutions finds.you can see output here[OutPut PDF file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcpEU.png)

Any help? Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried updating my existing pdf file. but it wasn't the correct solution to overcome this problem. Finally, I tried by creating new pdf file.

```
file_handle = fitz.open()  
first_page = file_handle.newPage() #file_handle[0] is getting issue
```

Answer (score 5):

This usually happens when the pdf has its own orientations, etc. Using [`page.clean_contents()`](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#Page.clean_contents) standardizes the page and should be used before the first insertion of any item.

Comment: dude this is a gem!!! bless you.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it seems to be an issue with the PDF file.
i fixed it by generating another copy of the pdf file.
i used photoshop then save as PDF.  you can also try "Print to PDF".
HTH

Comment: Your answer is ambiguous. Please, explain about the reasons. Why your solution should be worked?

Comment: i have no idea either.  i just read from another thread that there is something how the PDF was generated.  PyMuPDF has no mirror parameter, only rotation.  so I decided to test another PDF file, and the mirror issue was not present.